# Pathfinder/D&D Compatability

Tags: dnd-5e, pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e, dungeons-and-dragons

I've known for quite some time that the Pathfinder RPG is designed to be compatible with D&D 3.5e, however, I currently don't understand what the benefit of doing such a thing is.

Additionally, I was wondering if there is any way to combine Pathfinder with D&D 5e, and if there would be any benefit to that as well.

As I am not a Pathfinder player, my main question is are there any races, classes, spells, monsters, items, or other things that could be brought into D&D to improve the experience.

Comment: Do you have a clear question? You question is extremely vague: what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I've removed the question about 5e/Pathfinder compatibility. Please ask about that separately, since it is an entirely different question and a whole other can of worms.

Comment: Are you asking designer reasons or are you asking benefits for a player? it is rather broad and very unspecific.

Comment: I think the question was asking about a business / market perspective. What is the benefit **FOR the company PAIZO** of Pathfinder [...]

Comment: I notice you've rolled this back to its original version. Unfortunately the original version is too broad, as it does not fit our “one question post, one question” rule. As such I've now put a hold on this as “Too Broad”. If the edits offered by other editors were wrong and made your post no longer mean what you wanted to ask, you can use the comments here to discuss how to bring the question into line with our topic rules, while still preserving your intended meaning.

Comment: Hi Aidanowski. This question remains one we can't facilitate -- or rather it's three widely separate questions, only the first of which we can facilitate, and which would need to be asked separately even if we could facilitate them (we can't). In order, they are: (paragraph 1) What's the benefit of being backwards compatible with D&D 3.5e? That's reasonable and something we can answer objectively. (paragraph 2) Can we combine D&D 5e and Pathfinder somehow, and would there be some benefit? -- We can't tell you whether there's benefit, but conversion guides are a whole separate request. [con't]

Comment: (paragraph 3) What would we bring from Pathfinder into D&D [some edition] is wholly subjective, and more a topic of discussion of what one would individually convert, which is fair [to ask on a forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go) but won't work out here because there's no best/correct answer to that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Pathfinder essentially exists as a backlash to 4th edition Dungeons and Dragons - it is derived directly from the third edition ruleset, intended to try and fix some of its biggest issues without significantly changing the underlying ruleset - in comparison to 4th edition, which was a drastic change to the system that proved highly unpopular with a large subset of D&D fans. It's also published by a different company, Paizo, taking advantage of the very permissive OGL license that 3/3.5e D&D were published under (another thing which 4e dropped, which people were also unhappy about).

The target audience was essentially people who already liked 3.5e D&D, wanted more 3.5e D&D, and probably already owned a lot of 3.5e products. It was therefore in Paizo's interest to make it a selling point that existing 3.5e material was broadly compatible with their new rules, so that customers would feel able to take advantage of their existing 3.5e content (and the time and money they had invested in that) and would not feel that they were essentially throwing it away by transitioning to a new system.

The "compatibility" is basically that with a little bit of effort you can translate 3.5e content into Pathfinder's rules relatively easily - Paizo produced guides on how to copy 3.5e characters into Pathfinder. As a direct derivative of 3.5e rules, Pathfinder is even sometimes referred to as "3.PF" or "3.75" D&D.

The same cannot be said for Pathfinder and 5e D&D, as that did not exist when Pathfinder was created (and so could not be designed for). Though 5e is certainly closer to the 3e/3.5e ruleset than 4e is, it's still significantly different to the degree that translating material is not the relatively simple job it is for 3.5e->Pathfinder conversion. Wizards of the Coast don't have a great deal of interest in keeping mechanical compatibility with older versions of their own game, let alone the derivative version of their old game published by a third party.

Comment: Its worth mentioning that 4e had no OGL license, which is why paizo decided to stay with 3.5.

Comment: Didn't Paizo stay with 3.5 because that was what their target audience wanted?

Comment: I think it's fair to say that Pathfinder's reason for existing is that 3.5 players wanted more 3.5-type stuff, but also that it is only able to exist because of the OGL. The former actually drove its creation; the latter created the environment where it was possible.

Comment: @Quentin No, Paizo had *planned* to move to 4e along with everyone else. Though there were players who wanted to stick with 3.5e, they weren't considered a viable market at first. It took a backlash among 3rd-party D&D companies to make the post-3.5e market viable. That backlash came when WotC took months to release a 3rd-party license, and then when they finally did it was incredibly restrictive (the GSL), making doing business with 4e basically impossible. Paizo created PF in order to move the dwindling 3.5e market to a living game, and grow that market.

Answer (score 11):

It is worth keeping in mind that Pathfinder was published as a response to WotC announcing the end of their 3.5 range. Piazo produced it as a direct replacement.

> I currently don't understand what the benefit of doing such a thing is.

It allows players who know 3.5 to move to Pathfinder with a minimum of effort. They can also easily convert their characters.

It allows supplements for 3.5 (such as monsters, scenarios, items, classes, feats, etc) to be adapted to Pathfinder with a minimum of effort. D&D 3.5 has a *huge* amount of support material written for it (both first and third party).